# Laravel3: How can I forward a string to a function?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-3

I have something like this:

```
Route::get('admin/user/modify', 'admin@user_modify');
```

But I should convert it to something like this:

```
Route::get('admin/user/modify/(:string)', 'admin@user_modify (with $string)');
```

Basically, I want to pass a string variable to my function.

How can I do this?

One more thing, what if the user doesn't pass a value and only browse `admin/user/modify/`, what will happen then? Should I manually check it or can I return it to 404 etc. if the value is not entered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

In your routes.php:

```
Route::get('users/edit/(:any)', array('as' => 'edit_user', 'uses' => 'users@edit'));
```

In your controller:

```
public function get_edit($id)
{
     return View::make('users.edit')
        ->with('user', User::find($id))
        ->with('title', 'Edit User');
}
```

if the user doesn't pass a value and only browse admin/user/modify/ will show a 404. If you want another behaviour you can do something like this:

```
    //Return a 404 response or what you prefer
    Route::get('admin/users/update', function(){
        return Response::error('404');
    });
```

Comment: Is "uses" a special name in laravel?

Comment: Uses: Registering a filtered route that points to a controller action.  http://laravel.com/docs/routing